# Is it possible to wait until the ask method returns a response

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Using `actions-on-google`, when handling an intent and then using `conv.ask()` to send a response to the agent, is it possible to wait until the request has been successfully sent and then continue doing something else? Is there a way to `await` the response of the `ask` method?

My idea is to tell the agent to say something, manually time playing a sound (mp3) after the `ask` method has been successfully sent to the agent. Right now it takes a bit of time for the agent to receive the request, say the thing and then play the sound. The request gets sent, but not received instantly so the sound that I am playing plays way before the agent has said something.

Is that something possible?

**Update**

Right now I'm using SSML to make two different voices speak in one intent. The idea of it is that we have two "personalities" talking, and each personality has a different voice. Currently, in SSML using some attributes to do that. Let's call them P1 and P2. P1 starts by saying something, and as soon as it ends a sound of a blender gets played. Right after the sound is playing the second personality P2 starts talking, and then P1 then "replies" to it, but that all happens in one intent response. That's the idea I'm trying to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to play audio immediately after saying something, it more sounds like you want to use a [Media](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#media_responses) response as part of what you're sending back. Your mp3 file must be available at an HTTPS address, although that address can be anything you want as long as the device can resolve it. Since it will be on the same server the webhook is running on, and the webhook has to have a public HTTPS URL, then presumably the audio will (or can) as well.

If your interest is in knowing that latency, you can probably time the difference between when you send the response and when the device requests the mp3 file.

There is no direct way to know when the Assistant has finished saying the text, but you can use tricks with the Media response to get some idea depending on your needs.

**Update** based on your use case.

If you're doing it all as one response, and it fits in that response, and your audio is just a few seconds long, then you can do it using SSML as a single response. That part seems fine.

If the audio is longer or you want more of a back and forth between your personalities, then you can use the Media response to play the audio (even a very short empty audio). At the end of the audio playing, it sends an event to the Action and you can then continue to the next step in your personalities responding.

Comment: Is it possible to play a local media file? I checked the documentation, this is something that could work in my use case, but the only hiccup right now is that I don't see if its possible to play local media files.

Comment: Perhaps you can explain your use case better? It isn't clear why this would matter, however, I've answered your question. It really depends what you mean by "local".

Comment: Alright. So right now I'm using SSML to make two different voices speak in one intent. The idea of it is that we have two "personalities" talking, and each personality has a different voice. Currently, in SSML using some attributes to do that. Let's call them P1 and P2. P1 starts by saying something, and as soon as it ends a sound of a blender gets played. Right after the sound is playing the second personality P2 starts talking, and then P1 then "replies" to it, but that all happens in one intent response. That's the idea I'm trying to implement.

Comment: And what I mean by local is a file in the current server that the webhooks are being handled in, and not a file that is uploaded to an external service such as google cloud storage for example with a URL that I can feed it to the MediaResponse.

Comment: I put your use case in your question, and addressed it in my answer. I've also updated my answer to address your use of "local".

Comment: Thank you! One last question, your opinion actually, can I do the first part of P1 talking and the sound through DialogFlow GUI and then catch the media event and continue the P2 and P1 rest text in the event handler? Will it keep the parameters and the contexts automatically or do I have to feed them back again manually through the server handlers?

Comment: It depends how you're using your contexts. Context rules still apply, of course - the Media event is just like other Intents, as if the user was replying. If you do have further questions or problems with that aspect - open a new question and give examples of what Contexts and values you're expecting.